# Where em um Array JSON Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

Como posso fazer para selecionar apenas os registros que possuam o valor "18" nesse *JSON*?

```
'{"filtros":[
    {
        "tipo":"caracteristicas",
        "operador":"=",
        "valor":{"18":[12]}
    }
  ]}'
```

Tentei usar a comparação com o `@>` mas não deu certo, pois ele não me retorna o registro.

```
SELECT opcoes FROM pagina WHERE (opcoes->>'filtros')::jsonb @> '[18]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver do seguinte modo:

```
SELECT opcoes FROM pagina WHERE opcoes::jsonb @> '{"filtros":[{"valor":{"18":[]}}]}';
```

Comment: Mas isso vai funcionar apenas quando tiver só um filtro, não?

Comment: Funcionou com mais filtros. Na base tenho vários registros e com o select acima funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 1):

O complicado aqui é que filtros é um array, então você não pode fazer a consulta diretamente, tem que percorrer para cada posição dele.

Para isso, você deve usar a função `jsonb_array_elements(jsonb)`. Ela vai transformar a lista de resultados em uma "tabela" e você pode dar trabalhar com esses resultados.

Imagine que você tenha em vez de 1 elemento dentro de filtros, tenha 2 elementos. Exemplo:

```
'{"filtros":[
    { 
        "tipo":"caracteristicas", 
        "operador":"=",  
        "valor":{"18":[12]}
    },
    { 
        "tipo":"caracteristicas", 
        "operador":"=",  
        "valor":{"19":[12]}
    }
]}'
```

Com `(opcoes->>'filtros')::jsonb` você vai escolher todos os elementos desse array. Com `jsonb_array_elements` você vai transformá-lo em tuplas:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements((opcoes->>'filtros')::jsonb) FROM pagina limit 1;
                    jsonb_array_elements
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"tipo": "caracteristicas", "valor": {"18": [12]}, "operador": "="}
 {"tipo": "caracteristicas", "valor": {"19": [12]}, "operador": "="}
(2 rows)
```

Mas você ainda tem q ver se um desses caras tem o valor "18". Imagino eu que você queria olhar especificamente o campo `valor` e não qualquer campo. Para isso você tem que referenciar ele na consulta:

```
SELECT jsonb_array_elements((opcoes->>'filtros')::jsonb)->>'valor' FROM pagina limit 1;
   ?column?
--------------
{"18": [12]}
{"19": [12]}
(2 rows)
```

Agora basta ver se o "valor" tem a chave '18' usando o operador `?` (sempre lembrando que tem q transformar o resultado em um jsonb pra permitir a consulta).

```
SELECT (jsonb_array_elements((opcoes->>'filtros')::jsonb)->>'valor')::jsonb ? '18' FROM pagina limit 1;
   ?column?
--------------
t
f
(2 rows)
```

Como esse resultado pode retornar mais de uma linha para cada tupla armazenada, você pode colocar ele numa subconsulta para fazer o filtro, algo como:

```
SELECT opcoes FROM pagina WHERE id in (
    SELECT DISTINCT id FROM pagina WHERE 
        (jsonb_array_elements((opcoes->>'filtros')::jsonb)->>'valor')::jsonb ? '18'
    );
```

Comment: Em partes deu certo, mas quando tentei usar o SELECT (jsonb_array_elements((opcoes->>'filtros')::jsonb)->>'valor')::jsonb ? '18' FROM pagina limit 1; que pro meu caso seria o mais adequado ele retorna erro: 

ERRO:  sintaxe de entrada é inválida para tipo json
DETAIL:  Fim da entrada esperado, encontrado ",".
CONTEXT:  dado JSON, linha 1: 1,...

Comment: O que imprime a consulta:

    SELECT (jsonb_array_elements((opcoes->>'filtros')::jsonb)->>'valor'‌​) FROM pagina limit 1;

Comment: Sim, isso deu certo, mas o problema foi quanto tentei filtrar pelo registro 18 conforme colocastes no penúltimo SQL

Comment: Eu queria ver o resultado dessa consulta, porque o que parece que ele esta falando é que o json contido em valor é invalido.

Comment: Consegui resolver de um jeito diferente, fazendo assim: SELECT opcoes FROM pagina WHERE opcoes::jsonb @> '{"filtros":[{"valor":{"18":[]}}]}'; mas o que tu me passou me ajudou a chegar na solução